# Как скрыть клавиатуру по нажатию клавиши "Enter"?

Tags: android

Как скрыть клавиатуру по нажатию клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clEtAddCourse);
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                   // hide keyboard
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо ) вот что ещё нашла. 
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);